# Confused with the output of the following python list

Tags: python, list, arraylist, iterator

Ever since I saw this code, I am getting confused.

```
a=[0,1,2,3]

for a[-1] in a:
   print(a[-1])
```

So according to code, a[-1] should be the last element, which is 3, and hence the code should print the following output according to me:

```
3
2 
1
0
```

But the output I got was the following:

```
0
1
2
2
```

Can anybody help how the following code is getting executed hopefully with a step by step iteration.

Comment: What do you think does `for a[-1] in a:` do?

Comment: It is not really clear what parts of the code you do understand. Can you please clarify why you think the code would output 3,2,1,0?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What does `for a[-1] in a:` do?

Comment: I just found this code on a exam and since then its been on my mind that what does that for `a[1] in a: ` do in that code to get that following output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what your code does, first, let's see what below code does:

```
    a = [0,1,2,3]
    for item in a:
        print(item)
```

This code can be converted to the following index-based for loop:

```
    for i in range(len(a)):
        item = a[i]
        print(item)
```

**Output of above snippets**

```
0
1
2
3
```

In the above code, you are iterating over the list *a*, one by one in left to right order and assigning each value to the variable *item*. Then you are printing that item variable.

Now, coming to what your code does, let's convert it to index-based for loop

```
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[-1] = a[i] # See, how you are re-assigning the last element of list
        print(a[-1])
```

At each iteration, value of *i* , *a[i]* and *a* would be as following:

```
first iteration, i =0, a[i] = 0, a = [0,1,2,0], output of a[-1] = 0
second iteration, i = 1, a[i] = 1, a = [0,1,2,1], output of a[-1] = 1
third iteration, i = 2, a[i] = 2, a = [0,1,2,2], output of a[-1] = 2
final iteration, i = 3, a[i] = 2, a = [0,1,2,2], output of a[-1] = 2
```

That's the reason you are seeing the output as 0,1,2,2

If you want to print the array in reverse order, you shouldn't assign the values to last element of array, modify your code as below

```
    for item in a[::-1]
     print (item)
```

Here a[::-1] reverses the array, and then you are using a scoped variable item to iterate over the reversed array.

Comment: Well thank you for the answer. I was getting much confused but your step-by-step execution helped.

Answer (score 1):

`a[-1]` in the for loop resets the last element at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse a list, you should try `a[::-1]`, So as per your requirement,

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for item in a[::-1]:
   print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't want to reverse the list, I just want to know the working of the part `for a[-1] in a:` does in the following code to get that output ever since I saw it.  Seems I need to rephrase it better next time.